# Output characteristics of a CE Transistor

Tags: transistors

In the saturation region the emitter base junction and collector base junction both are forward biased.It is said that in this region Ic does not depend upon the input current Ib .Why is it so?Explain.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a "CB Transistor"? Is the Collector Base junction really forward biased? Then why is there still flowing current **into** the collector when an NPN transistor is in saturation mode? If the CB junction is in forward should the current not flow **out** of the collector?

Comment: By CE(changed) I meant Common Emitter Transistor.

Comment: @Mithra When a BJT is operating saturated, it's collector is very much like a voltage source with its voltage very close to the emitter voltage. It is no longer a current source with \$I_\text{C}\approx \beta\:I_\text{B}\$. But putting it into saturation is a matter of the external circuit. Not just the BJT by itself.

Answer (score 1):

### Preface

It's probably easiest to see the reason by looking at an example circuit and discussing it for a moment. Let's start with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feh95K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This isn't a complicated circuit. We intend to supply the base with a constant \$20\:\mu\text{A}\$. However, we will vary \$V_1\$ from \$0\:\text{V}\$ to some arbitrarily large voltage, say \$20\:\text{V}\$.

Before we do that, let's do some thought experiments on the above circuit. For those experiments in our head, let's assume that the 2N2222A BJT has \$\beta=200\$ when in active mode (not saturated.)

---

### Active mode

If \$Q_1\$ doesn't exhibit the Early Effect (let's assume the BJT is ideal in that sense) and isn't saturated (whatever that means will become clearer, shortly), then it follows that the collector current should be \$I_\text{C}=\beta\cdot I_\text{B}\$. Since \$\beta=200\$ and since \$I_\text{B}=20\:\mu\text{A}\$, we find that \$I_\text{C}=4\:\text{mA}\$. This is because the collector is acting like a current sink (in this case) that depends upon the base current and \$\beta\$ to set its value. It doesn't care about the value of \$R_\text{C}\$. If \$R_\text{C}\$ is small and doesn't drop much voltage, then the collector's voltage will rise up to whatever is needed so that the current in \$R_\text{C}\$ is \$4\:\text{mA}\$. End of story.

Now, this works okay so long as the collector voltage doesn't "have to go" negative. (Because there is no way it can.) So. If \$V_1=4\:\text{V}\$ and if the collector voltage is \$0\:\text{V}\$ (the lowest possible voltage it can reach, in theory), then the current in \$R_\text{C}\$ can still be \$4\:\text{mA}\$ and the rules seem to still be met.

In reality, though, if the collector falls below the base voltage (which must be more than \$0\:\text{V}\$, obviously) then the collector-base junction starts going into forward-biased mode (it starts acting like an active diode.) So, it is best to see that saturation occurs, starting at the point where the collector voltage equals the base voltage. Beyond this point, there is very little ability for the collector to drop further in voltage and the collector will stop acting quite so much as a current sink and start acting more like a voltage source that is close in value to the emitter voltage.

---

### Saturation

Saturation occurs when the base-collector junction moves increasingly into the forward-biased region (when the collector voltage falls below the base voltage.) The further below the base voltage that the collector voltage goes, the deeper into saturation is the BJT. That's the simple idea here.

This happens in the above circuit when the variable voltage, \$V_1\$, falls below about \$4.7\:\text{V}\$. (When the collector falls below the base voltage.)

At this point, the collector cannot move much. It can go from perhaps \$700\:\text{mV}\$ above the emitter to perhaps \$70\:\text{mV}\$ above the emitter. But that's about it. So there's very little wiggle-room at this point. Once the base-collector junction moves into its forward-biased region, there's very little adjustment left over for the collector voltage. It's mostly constant and can only vary a little. So it now "looks like" a voltage source and no longer like a current sink.

---

### Plotting the data

Here's the output from Spice for the above schematic (Early Effect removed by changing the Spice parameter, **VA**.)

[image]

As you can see, the current in \$R_\text{C}\$ rises upward as \$R_\text{C}\$ rises, at first. This is because the collector is acting like a voltage source with a voltage close to the emitter voltage. So as \$V_1\$ rises upward the current in \$R_\text{C}\$ rises along with it. Just like you'd expect if the collector were a voltage source near the emitter voltage.

However, once \$R_\text{C}\$ rises enough and exceeds something a little more than \$4\:\text{V}\$, then the collector switches over and now acts like a current sink with only \$4\:\text{mA}\$. This \$4\:\text{mA}\$ induces a fixed voltage drop across  \$R_\text{C}\$. And so the collector voltage rises with \$V_1\$.

I've plotted \$V_\text{CE}\$ in green so that you can see it stays fixed and close to zero, at first. But then follows upward with \$V_1\$ once \$V_1\$ exceeds about \$4.7\:\text{V}\$. Note that \$I_{\text{R}_\text{C}}\$ remains fixed at about \$4\:\text{mA}\$ once \$V_1\$ is large enough to support the BJT in active mode (as opposed to saturated mode.) Prior to that, the BJT must be saturated. And when it is saturated, you can easily see that the current in \$R_\text{C}\$ simply follows \$V_1\$.

### Summary

In short, in saturation mode the collector current doesn't depend on the base current. It depends instead on the supply voltage. Easily seen on the chart above. However, once it is in active mode and no longer in saturated mode, the collector current is fixed and steady and is entirely based upon the base current and the value of \$\beta\$.